# Relation between solution spaces of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider an $m\times n$ matrix $A$ and an $m\times 1$ column vector $u$. Let $(A|u)$ represent the matrix $A$ with $u$ appended as the last column. Given an equation,

$(A|u)x=b$

Are there relations between the solution space of the equation above and the same equation replacing $u$ with another vector $v$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us write $x=\left(\begin{matrix}y\\z\end{matrix}\right)$, with $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $z\in\mathbb{R}$. Then we have:

\begin{align*}
\left(A,u\right)\left(\begin{matrix}y\\z\end{matrix}\right)=&b\\
\left(A,v\right)\left(\begin{matrix}\tilde{y}\\\tilde{z}\end{matrix}\right)=&b
\end{align*}
which gives us
\begin{align*}
A(y-\tilde{y})=v\tilde{z}-uz.
\end{align*}
This tells us that $A\Delta y\in span(u,v)$, with $\Delta y=y-\tilde{y}$. Note, however, that every two partial solutions $y$ and $\tilde{y}$ satisfy this condition, but that not necessarily every values for $y$ and $\tilde{y}$ satisfying this condition are partial solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The rank of A|u and A|v can be different or equal dipending on the chioice of u and v so the dimensions of the null space are not necessarly the same. As long as I can see you can just say that they have b in common